# Python Spyder: unable to connect to remote ipython kernel

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I am trying to connect a Spyder IDE from my local to an Ipython kernel that run on my server.

In Spyder the prompt to connect to that "existing kernel" is the following:

[image]

I connect to my already set-up Jupyter notebook console on the server and create a new notebook/kernel.
I type `%connect-info` and retrieve the json that gets created. I paste it in an editor on my local and save it as kernel.json.

In the connection info, i paste a link to a file that i called kernel.json and that is on my local. That file contains the following:

```
{
  "hb_port": 52540,
  "stdin_port": 47033,
  "signature_scheme": "hmac-sha345",
  "shell_port": 29460,
  "transport": "tcp",
  "iopub_port": 60831,
  "ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "key": "43e4932c-e819-47ba-3333-66e45d7bc6de",
  "control_port": 20567,
  "kernel_name": ""
}
```

I click "this is a remote kernel" and fill host name with `blabla@ip-172-31-26-235`
I tried using both my ssh key in the second line/ or my password to the server in the third (i have both to connect to my server).

Is there anything obviously wrong that you see in that protocol?

Any clear explanation that explain as a step by step the protocol for the Spyder specifically is more than welcome.
**Please do not send links to other questions. I read them carefully and it didnt help me solve my problem.**

EDIT: I am receiving error `"paramiko is not available"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> blabla@ip-172-31-26-235:

that `:` colon in the end is a part of string? I just tried - it workes for me (connected to my own machine with name@host & password).

Comment: > "paramiko is not available"

pip install paramiko ?

Comment: regarding the colon: yes its a typo; i tried both with and without stating the port, neither of which worked. Are you using linux or windows on your local?  I've seen in some other post that the problem might be stemming from windows/linux connection.

Comment: I also tried pip install paramiko on my local, but it says it is already there.

Comment: Did you succeeed to connect Spyder to remote ipython sever ?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working ... I had to run Spyder as an administrator in Windows, and then enter `!pip install paramiko` in the spyder iPython console. After that, you can restart spyder normally and it will connect to a remote kernel.

Running pip from the command line just installed paramiko in the default IPython interpreter as opposed to the tweaked one that Spyder runs.

In my attempts to solve this, I did install the current C++ compiler from Microsoft, before running `!pip install paramiko` so that may or may not be necessary.

> *See: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_14.0_standalone:_Build_Tools_for_Visual_Studio_2017_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ARM.2C_ARM64.29*